# slider on android home screen

Tags: java, android

I am creating a application which needs to show all the time to user, User also can hide that app, When he drag his finger from left to right or right to left(On android screen, No matter in which application he was) then all of my document list will be shown. 
I know its all most impossible, But some apps are all ready doing this, I dont know how this is possible.

I searched on google but didn't find any useful link. 
Here look at this snapshot what i want.

[image]

App which is using this:-
Multitasking

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it is doing it actually.

Comment: Anybody get the solution for this problem?